# Where could some html tags be necessary?

Tags: html

I was walking through the new html 5 features and I saw and tried a lot of new tags to see what kind of affect they have on the browser but honestly I didn't see much difference.

So lets talk about `<time>` tag as an example :

> If you write down `<time>10:00</time>`
>   obviously it shows 10:00 on the page
>   but I mean I was expecting something
>   advanced like formatting. For example,
>   if I write `<time>10</time>` it could
>   format it to 10:00 instead of just
>   showing 10 on the page.
>
> Also another example can be `<time
>   datetime="2008-02-14">Valentines
>   day</time>` it also shows just
>   `Valentine days` on the page and
>   nothing more. No tooltip, not a fancy
>   animation nothing like them.

They are tags like this, and if it is needed I most probably will use span or something else and use some kinda js code to make it more appealing and that's all.

So I am not just talking about `<time>` tag here, any other tags like that.

Eventually, my question is why and where we need to use them.

My best guess it to make source code more readable by codes and crawlers maybe or they can be used for semantic web. But even these answers didn't satisfy me.

Comment: It's worth reading PPK's discussion of the `<time>` element, and its problems: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/04/making_time_saf.html

Comment: It is good but it is not that much relevant to my questions because he is talking much about the philosophy behind `<time>`. I think my question is more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are definitely used for adding semantic meaning to the markup.  For instance:

```
<div class="post">
<h1>Example Blog Post</h1>
   <div class="entry">
      <p>Blog text goes here...</p>
   </div>
   <div class="entryFooter">
      <p> Posted in example category.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

is not as readable as using the HTML5 tags of:

```
<article>
   <header>
      <h1>Example Blog Post</h1>
   </header>
   <p>Blog text goes here...</p>
   <footer>
      <p>Posted in example category.</p>
   </footer>
</article>
```

It also helps to make the markup more readable to developers and I think it makes styling a lot easier. The `<time>` tag falls in this boat as well as it provides more semantic meaning in your markup than a `<span>` tag would. This way programs in the future or browsers might be able to use that semantic data to change the time per the user's local time zone as an example.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I really like your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Semantic markup gives power back to users**

It is possible that you can write something like:

```
<time datetime="2010-10-20" />
```

and the browser will render it as:

```
3 days ago
```

or in some other languages of the user's preference.

Semantic markups are all about these kind of things. We are tagging text for their 'meaning', instead of for visual styling. The styling is just an extra. Once you get the meaning right, the **user** can style these markups to their preference, not to the author's preference. This wasn't possible with style markups, a bold markup may be used for adding emphasis, or it may be used for headings, while in other places it may be used for the first paragraph of an article. A time markup is always used for time, an emphasis markup is always used for adding emphasis, and nothing else.

Many browsers support user stylesheet to allow a user to override the stylesheet used by the website, but they are very rarely used since they are currently useless, because they apply styling indiscriminately (and because of the lack of tool support, not every users fancies writing CSS code; but we can argue that the lack of tool support is because there are not many that will use these tools, given the limited usefulness they have with formatting markup).

Then, there is the non-visual browsers; some people with visual disabilities uses aural browser. These browsers doesn't work well with formatting markups.

Comment: Okay, till a new purpose coming out, the meaning of this new tags will be for semantic web and developer readable source codes.

Answer (score 3):

The semantic tags are, as you guess, used for adding semantics to web pages.  Browsers won't generally render the differently by default, but you certainly can style them how you want with CSS.

Comment: So they don't have any fancy things for these specific elements in the html 5 specifications or browsers just want to render them like that?

Comment: No.  How would you expect a browser to render a time differently, for example?

Comment: Well, actually I gave an example in my first post, but let me give again -- for example : it can format 10 to 10:00 if minute section doesn't specified.

Comment: But then a French user opens the page, and gets disappointed that he isn't seeing "10h00". Or, suppose it does get rendered in the French way - the pixel width of "10:00" and "10h00" might be different and not at all what the designer intended. Or, maybe the designer really wanted "10h" or "10 o'clock", or, indeed, "10". This way it is all under control of the creator of markup.

Comment: @Armadan -- but isn't that why there is a localization option in browsers. If a french user opens the page, it will be rendered according to his browser settings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think html tags should be used to provide any style information - that's for css. However, you should use the new tags when appropriate. If you're making an html 5 website, why use the `<span>` tag for a time, when you could use the time tag? A lot of these new tags are no different that their predecessors in their functionality, but they do allow you to add more meaning to your mark-up.